# Wrapper script for vim --remote

Tags: vimscript, linux

I need to set on my Linux box `VIM`  as default mime application for editing text file. On `zsh` I managed to wrap a function from vim --remote. But I would like to use it for default xdg-mime application (in the same way `emacsclient` is doing for emacs).

Comment: Can't you use GVim instead?

Comment: No.  GVim is not and wont be installed.

Comment: If it helps: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xdg-open` relies on `.desktop` files, so you'll have to create on and then associate it with the right mimetypes. If you can't/won't use GVim, you can still piggy-back on its `.desktop` file.

```
$ grep -v Comment /usr/share/applications/gvim.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=GVim
GenericName=Text Editor
GenericName[de]=Texteditor
TryExec=gvim
Exec=gvim -f %F
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=vim
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
```

Copy the contents to a `vim.desktop`, while:

- replacing `gvim` with `vim` for `TryExec`
- using your `vim --remote` command for `Exec`. `%F`, as you might have deduced, will be replaced with the filenames.

Then, copy this to `~/.local/share/applications` and mark it as executable:

```
cp vim.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/vim.desktop
```

In whatever method you use to access launchers for your installed apps (Unity's Dash, GNOME Shell's Overview, MATE/XFCE/Clementine's menu, etc.), you should see a new Vim entry, indicating that the `.desktop` file was correctly created.

Now, to associate it with text files, you can do:

```
xdg-mime default vim.desktop text/plain
```

Comment: @EnricoPirani out of curiosity, what is your `vim --remote` command? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: you mean the `zsh` snippet?

Comment: @EnricoPirani yes, or whatever you will be using in the `.desktop` file.

Comment: For `vim.desktop` as you wrote I used `vim --remote %F`

Comment: @EnricoPirani Sigh. Being Vim, I imagined some complex incantation. :D